# Internet Connection Sharing and VMware with Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have Windows 7 host, 
Ubuntu Guest and VMware workstation and only have a 3G Dialup connection.

How would I got about setting up internet connection sharing on Windows 7, then configuring VMware networking to get internet access in Ubuntu?

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Usually if you have a Virtual Machine inside a host that has internet, you can set the HyperVisor (VMware) to let the guest access it through the settings. Launch VMware and go into the settings for that machine and set it to allow the internet to pass through to the guest. Although I am speaking of how I would do it with VirtualBox, most of these things can be similar

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is for the Ubuntu VM to be a user of the internet (ie not a server), then you should be able to use teh Virtual Network Editor set up a VMnet that is NAT'd to your host's 3G connection.  Then edit the VM's settings so that the ethernet device is connected to the VMnet NAT'd to the 3G connection.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to install VMware tools if I am not mistaken